Write in memory not applied
I'm currently writing code for the Arduino UNO R4 Minima (which uses the ARMv7-M ISA). Part of the code is in C++, the other is in assembly. I have no problem when manipulating registers, returning results and so on. In this assembly code, I'm trying to implement a version of strcpy (called _strcpy) in assembly. But when I run the code, the destination string isn't modified.
Can someone help me please ?
Here is the c++ part:
extern "C" {
  void _strcpy(char* d, char* s); //l'adresse de la destination est mise dans R0, celle de la source dans R1
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  char* srcstr = " premiere chaine - source ";
  char* dststr = " deuxieme chaine - destination ";
  Serial.println("Avant recopie:");
  Serial.println(srcstr);
  Serial.println(dststr);
  Serial.println("Apres copie:");
  Serial.println(srcstr);
  Serial.println(dststr);
  delay(1000);
}

And here is the ARMv7-M assembly part:
.global _strcpy
_strcpy:
  PUSH {R2, R3}
  MOV R3, #0
loop:
  LDRB R2, [R1, R3]
  STRB R2, [R0, R3]
  ADD R3, #1
  CMP R2, #0
  BNE loop
  POP {R2, R3}
  BX LR

Here is the output I get in the serial monitor:
Avant recopie:
 premiere chaine - source 
 deuxieme chaine - destination 
Apres copie:
 premiere chaine - source 
 deuxieme chaine - destination


Your loop() function doesn't call _strcpy.  Use a debugger to single-step or set a breakpoint.

How is the normal strcpy implemented for this target? I assume you do not want to improve that, but to learn assembly programming.
